# prevent Linq-To-Nhibernate from updating Related tables

Tags: linq, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using Fluent NHibernate, and am attempting to update all the records for entity type "Files". I have eager loaded FileTypes along with it. By practice all tables have an UpdatedTime even if they are not necessary for use.

The problem I'm having is the following classic:

```
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM
```

This is coming from the FileType's "UpdatedTime = null" even though my update method is being called on a File.

I do not want to overwrite the null in FileType, in fact I don't want to update it at all.

It seems to me that i should be able to either elect to not include the related entities in the update via mapping, or I should be able to get it to leave that field as null instead of DateTime.min.

EDIT

Below I have provided a solution to the the datetime issue, however, it would be a superior answer to prevent the second table from updating in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out being relatively simple after more messing around. I changed the domain to use DateTime? instead of DateTime.

While this solved the problem, It is a bit 'hacky' and I would prefer to not update the second table.